# Project crash during screen switch

Tags: android, libgdx

I made a project using a Gradle setup.  Sometimes (seems pretty random), the game will just crash whenever it goes to switch screens, for example, when the game ends, it sometimes goes to the GameOver screen (which it should) and sometimes it'll crash.

Here is the LogCat output from when it crashed:

```
07-11 14:55:09.891: A/libc(8045): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x51506008 (code=1), thread 8474 (Thread-7978)
```

Anyone know any typical reasons why this crash would occur?

Comment: Gradle is a build system- it won't change the runtime behavior of your application. I would look elsewhere for the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you switch between screens, you are effectively telling the Blocks Editor to load a new project, and this takes a little time. Wait until the Blocks Editor is done loading the blocks for the new screen before changing things. Most especially, wait until the new screen has finished loading before clicking on blocks or links with the mouse. If you don't wait, you may get errors, or even lose blocks from your project.

Reference -> http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/colored-dots.html

Also, it might be helpful to look at this link: http://puravidaapps.com/manager.php

Comment: So would you suggest that each time the screens switch, I should add something that says "loading" & disables user input?  Or something like that which gives the new screen time to load?

Comment: Yes, you need to allow the screens to finish the behind process. Also, you may try to destroy the main screen and try to reload it using gameover screen to make it fresh. This might avoid crash

Comment: @SerhatC good call on letting the game load.  When the game switches to a new screen, I allow it 2-3 seconds to load before any user input is registered.  Thanks a lot for your help!